# how do i access a child object using django.views

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models Team, Player. Player has a foriegn-key to teams.

Now i want to have a view and have defined my urls.py like this

```
    url(r'^team/(?P<team_id>)/player/(?P<player_id>)/$', 'djangocricket.Cricket.views.player'),
```

if i define my view like

```
def player(request, team_id, player_id):
    template = get_template('player.html')
    loggedinuser = request.user
    team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
    player = Player.objects.get(id=player_id)

    page_vars = Context({
        'loggedinuser': loggedinuser,
        'team': team,
        'player': player,
    })

    output = template.render(page_vars)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

it gives me this error.

```
url() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

help is much appreciated.

//mouse

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your urls.py statement. You need to add the view to call when this url is requested. url requires these two arguments.

```
url(r'^team/(<team_id>\w+)/player/(<player_id>\w+)', 'views.player'),
```

Also, as Béres Botond noted, I also thought the patterns looked incorrect. As he stated, add `?P` to the beginning of each pattern, just inside the parentheses.

Comment: I add it's considered good practice to add a name for the URL, thusly: `url(r'^team/(<team_id>\w+)/player/(<player_id>\w+)', 'view.player', name='team-player'),` which allows you to call it using `{% url team-player team.id player.id %}` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

In your url conf you also need to tell it what view that pattern points to. Furthermore the parameters in your pattern are not correctly defined. Should be something like this:

```
url(r'^team/(?P<team_id>\w+)/player/(?P<player_id>\w+)/$', 'myproject.myapp.views.player'),
```

For more details check out the urlconf docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/

Comment: i did this .. now my views.py look like this     url(r'^team/(?P<team_id>)/player/(?P<player_id>)/$', 'djangocricket.Cricket.views.player'),  .. but it gives me 404 error.